# Include page with specific anchor

Tags: html, user-interface, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I'am a beginner in jsf and I want to open an html page in a `p:dialog`.
When I use the `<ui: include>` to display the page like this:

```
<p:dialog  header="Dialog"  
           widgetVar="dlg"
           resizable="false" 
           dynamic="true"   
           fitViewport="true"> 

    <ui:include src="/resources/md.html" />

</p:dialog>
```

it works with no problem, but when I want to open the page in a specific anchor like this:

```
<p:dialog header="Dialog"
          widgetVar="dlg" 
          resizable="false" 
          dynamic="true"   
          fitViewport="true">     

    <ui:include src="/resources/md.html#anchor" />

</p:dialog>
```

it doesn't work.

Can somebody help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another solution using `iframe tag`, it works perfectly:

```
<p:commandLink value="iframe" onclick="PF('dlg').show()"   />


<p:dialog header="Dialog" widgetVar="dlg">         
<iframe height="500" width="800" src="/md.xhtml#anchor"></iframe>
</p:dialog>
```

No js need.

Comment: This has lots of disadvantages since this is a completely new page, no interaction etc.. Should only be used as a last resort!

Comment: I used this to display a read me file so i think that an iframe tag does the job

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt fails because your `md.html` is statically included inside 'parent' jsf page. Therefore only parent jsf page can be used to achieve *'go to anchor'* functionality.

To achieve what you want with an included page inside `p:dialog`, I would use simple java script.

**JS**

Add this JS function to your parent jsf page (page where dialog is defined)

```
function gotoAnchor(anchorID) {
    document.getElementById(anchorID).scrollIntoView();
}
```

**XHTML**

Add `onShow` attribute on `p:dialog` like this

```
<p:dialog ... onShow="gotoAnchor('anchorID')" ...> 
    <ui:include src="/resources/md.html" />
</p:dialog>
```

where anchorID is `id` of your anchor element inside `md.html` (in your example, its value is 'anchor').

On this way, when your `p:dialog` is shown, function gotoAnchor will be executed forcing page to scroll on required element.

Comment: I tried your solution unfortunately it's not working

Comment: I tried solution with simple 'md.html' page and simple jsf page...and its working OK. So if you want to get more help then post [mcve] so that somebody can reproduce your case .

Comment: I used th iframe tag to include the page and it works fine. thanks for your help